# React: How to reset variable on page refresh?

Tags: reactjs

I have several components in my React app that can update the "Status" attribute.

The default status of this attribute is "Desktop".

If I override the attribute in component 1, all other components in the dropdown menu are automatically updated.

The possible states are:

- Desktop
- Table
- Cell phone, Mobile phone

When the user submits the settings, the attributes are saved in the database, but this should only be a temporary value. When the user starts the app, the default value should always be "Desktop" again.

I'm not very familiar with React and maybe there is a better way to pass a default value to the child? However, the child element should also be able to update the parent component.

My question is related to my current architecture: how can I update the default `attribute ['state']` so that it always starts with 'desktop' when updating the page?

Comment: Hey Pennylane, you should provide some code. In addittion what is the purpose to save the settings in your database if you'll use the default value instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should useState() hook in react which creates a state and on refreshing the page value of state returns to the default value.

```
import {useState} from "react"

function myComponent(){

const [status,setStatus]=useState("Desktop")

...
```